# shell backdoor and ip restrictions

Tags: websecurity

Imagine for example :

1- I configured Restricted ssh access to my server by IP Address

/etc/hosts.allow

```
sshd,sshdfwd-X11: 192.168.2.111 217.40.111.121
```

/etc/hosts.deny

```
sshd,sshdfwd-X11:ALL
```

2- I configured restricted wp-admin access in nginx conf

```
location ~ ^/(wp-admin|wp-login\.php) {
                allow 1.2.3.4;
                deny all;
}
```

If now there is a wordpress vunerability that allow the attacker to upload a shell backdoor to my website. will he still be able to modify files in website directories, gain access, ect... ?

Comment: _"will he still be able to modify files in website directories, gain access, ect... ?"_ - presumably - especially as you haven't shared any details about how you've hardened you PHP+MySQL+WordPress install: while `/wp-admin/...` has IP filtering, that won't help stop any vulnerability in the public parts of your WordPress install. If you want a secure website then _don't use WordPress_ - instead use a static-site-generator that generates HTML files you upload to a locked-down host, e.g. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteHosting.html